# Passing info from JavaFX to Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, html, javafx

I'm trying to passing information(lattiude, longitude) to a google map in html webview. The problem is that the application don't start in netbeans. It returns that:

> Executing
>   C:\Users\Carlos\Documents\NetBeansProjects\OpenPilot\dist\run1883323097\OpenPilot.jar
>   using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\jre/bin/java
>   Exception in Application start method
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:367)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:305)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
>   Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start
>   method    at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:894)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:56)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:158)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   javafx.fxml.LoadException:  unknown path
>
> at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2617)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2595)    at
>   javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2425)     at
>   openpilot.OpenPilot.start(OpenPilot.java:29)  at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$8.run(LauncherImpl.java:837)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$7.run(PlatformImpl.java:335)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:301)
>     at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6$1.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$6.run(PlatformImpl.java:298)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)  at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$300(WinApplication.java:39)
>     at
>   com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$4$1.run(WinApplication.java:112)
>     ... 1 more Caused by: netscape.javascript.JSException: TypeError:
>   'undefined' is not a function     at
>   com.sun.webkit.dom.JSObject.fwkMakeException(JSObject.java:128)   at
>   com.sun.webkit.WebPage.twkExecuteScript(Native Method)    at
>   com.sun.webkit.WebPage.executeScript(WebPage.java:1410)   at
>   javafx.scene.web.WebEngine.executeScript(WebEngine.java:934)  at
>   openpilot.FXMLDocumentController.initialize(FXMLDocumentController.java:74)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)    ... 13 more
>   Exception running application openpilot.OpenPilot Java Result: 1

Here the code:

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML public WebView Map;





    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        URL MapURL = getClass().getResource("map.html");
        WebEngine WebEngine = Map.getEngine();
        WebEngine.load(MapURL.toExternalForm());
        String test = "40.3130432088809";
       WebEngine.executeScript("getCoordinates('40.3130432088809')");

    }    

}
```

And here the html with the map:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
    <script>
        var latitude;
        var longitude;
        function getCoordinates(latitude){
  this.latitude = latitude;

}
        var map;
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, -2.900390625)
            };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
   placeMarker(event.latLng);
});


}
function placeMarker(location) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location, 
        map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'rightclick', function() {
                    deleteMarker(marker);
                });

}

function deleteMarker(marker) {
                marker.setMap(null); 
            }
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: According to the stack trace, the issue is at line 29 of OpenPilot (somewhere in the start method). Can you show that code?

Answer (score 2):

You are almost certainly trying to execute the javascript before the page has loaded. You need to specify a handler to execute the script when the web engine has completed loading.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    URL MapURL = getClass().getResource("map.html");
    WebEngine WebEngine = Map.getEngine();
    WebEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {
        if (newState == State.SUCCEEDED) {
            WebEngine.executeScript("getCoordinates('40.3130432088809')");
        }
    });
    WebEngine.load(MapURL.toExternalForm());

}
```

Comment: Netbeans say me that this line is wrong: `WebEngine.getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((ov, oldState, newState) -> {` It said: `no suitable method found for addlistener`

Comment: add the import: `import javafx.concurrent.Worker.State;` and see if it fixes it

Comment: The problem is other.

Comment: Are you using Java 8? If not, convert the lambda expression to an inner class.